# can i use layername instead of layerid in identifyParams using arcgis api javascript 3.17?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is it possible to use layer name instaed of layerid in identifyparams.
However, over time, the layer order will change because I'll be adding new layers. Therefore, I want to refer to the layers by name, instead of id.can anyone suggest me please (am using arcgis api javascript api 3.17  example
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=find_popup)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that returns the layerId of a named layer.

```
  var map, layerIds = [];

  require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
    "dojo/_base/array"
  ], function (
    Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, array) {

    map = new Map("mapDiv", {
      sliderOrientation : "horizontal"
    });


    //Takes a URL to a non cached map service.
    var dynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer", {
    });

    map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer);

    map.on("load", function () {
        layerIds.push(getLayerIdFromMap(dynamicMapServiceLayer, "states"));
    });

    function getLayerIdFromMap(dynamicService, subLyrName) {
        var dLyr = map.getLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer.id);
        var layerId;
        array.some(dLyr.layerInfos, function (lyrInfo) {
            if (lyrInfo.name === subLyrName) {
                layerId = lyrInfo.id;
            }
        }, this);
        return layerId;
    }
  });
```

Comment: thank u kenbuja..   here is my code am not getting where should i apply the above code can u suggest me on that

Comment: I have made edited the code to show how to create a layerIds array that you can use in the line `identifyParams.layerIds = layerIds;` in your mapReady function. You can run the line `layerIds.push(getLayerIdFromMap(dynamicMapServiceLayer, "your layer name"));' multiple times for each layerId you want to be included in the IdentifyTask

Answer (score 0):

```
 require([
  "esri/map",
  "esri/InfoTemplate",
  "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
  "esri/tasks/IdentifyTask",
  "esri/tasks/IdentifyParameters",
  "esri/dijit/Popup",
  "dojo/_base/array",
  "esri/Color",
  "dojo/dom-construct",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
  Map, InfoTemplate, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, SimpleFillSymbol,
  SimpleLineSymbol, IdentifyTask, IdentifyParameters, Popup,
  arrayUtils, Color, domConstruct
) {

    var identifyTask, identifyParams;

    var popup = new Popup({
        fillSymbol: new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
          new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new Color([255, 0, 0]), 2), new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.25]))
    }, domConstruct.create("div"));



    map.on("load", mapReady);

    var mapserviceURL = "http://117.247.187.3:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Local/LocalVarunaAdminV1/MapServer";

    map.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(mapserviceURL));

    function mapReady() {
        map.on("click", executeIdentifyTask);
        //create identify tasks and setup parameters
        identifyTask = new IdentifyTask(mapserviceURL);

        identifyParams = new IdentifyParameters();
        identifyParams.tolerance = 3;
        identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
        //identifyParams.layerIds = [35, 0];
        identifyParams.layerOption = IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
        identifyParams.width = map.width;
        identifyParams.height = map.height;
    }


function executeIdentifyTask(event) {
        identifyParams.geometry = event.mapPoint;
        identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;

        var deferred = identifyTask
          .execute(identifyParams)
          .addCallback(function (response) {
              // response is an array of identify result objects
              // Let's return an array of features.
              return arrayUtils.map(response, function (result) {
                  var feature = result.feature;
                  var layerName = result.layerName;

                  feature.attributes.layerName = layerName;
                  if (layerName === 'Assembly') {
                      var taxParcelTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Assembly Details", "AssemblyCode:${AssemblyCode}<br /> AssemblyName:${AssemblyName}");
                      feature.setInfoTemplate(taxParcelTemplate);
                  }
                  else if (layerName === 'District Hospital') {
                      console.log(feature.attributes.AssemblyCode);
                      var buildingFootprintTemplate = new InfoTemplate("District Hospital Details", "HealthFaci Name:${HealthFaci}<br /> CategoryNa:${CategoryNa}<br /> AssemblyCode :${AssemblyCode}");
                      feature.setInfoTemplate(buildingFootprintTemplate);
                  }
                  return feature;
              });
          });
```

this is my code here am adding layerids maually can u suggest me whre ti apply the above code.